# CS0103 C# The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am facing issue while running c# code, here is snippet

```
namespace LDAP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creating an LdapConnection instance 
            LdapConnection ldapConn = new LdapConnection();

            //Connect function will create a socket connection to the server
            ldapConn.Connect(ldapHost, ldapPort);

            //Bind function will Bind the user object Credentials to the Server
            ldapConn.Bind(userDN, userPasswd);
        }
    }
}
```

After running program I am getting below error message
CS0103  The name 'ldapHost' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Where does `ldapHost` come from? Where is it declared? Did you copy/pasted this code from somewhere?

Comment: `ldapHost` and `ldapPort` are nowhere declared in your code. Neither `userDN` and `userPassword`.

Comment: That's because it *doesn't* exist (at least not in the code you showed us). Is there some other code that you haven't shown us? Where does this value come from?